# How to stop timer in pygame when it reaches a certain situation

Tags: python, timer, pygame

Hi I'm writing a code for memory game (a.k.a. card matching game) right now and I'm using a timer in pygame to tell how long the player took to make every card uncovered (matched every pair in card deck completely).

```
self.score = pygame.time.get_ticks() // 1000
```

this is what I wrote to check the time and I want to make this stop when all the cards are uncovered
is there any way that I can make is stop? I've searched a bit but nothing looked suitable for what I need now.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-6iDRyPoVg&feature=youtu.be
this is how it's suppose to look like.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `pygame.time.get_ticks()` returns the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called.

I think a better approach is to remember the time of the *first* card-click, and then compare this with the time of the *last* card-click.

For example:

```
### Card was clicked
if ( game_start_time == 0 ):
    game_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()   # game start time

    ...


    if ( cards_left_covered == 0 ):
        # calculate the elapsed time
        game_end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.score = ( game_end_time - game_start_time ) // 1000  # seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the timer to stop, set the miliseconds argument equal to 0. When the cards are all covered you might want to say something like this: cards_flipped_time = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time).

Hopefully that helped

Comment: I'm also printing the timer as a score.  would doing this change the number that's displayed on the screen as score? cause it's not suppose to change. Thanks!!